# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor with socket.shutdown()

Tags: python, sockets

I'm currently trying to get a hang of how sockets work.

I've followed an [online tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) & the [python HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html)

I have a server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
    
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1' #standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 9999

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
serversocket.listen()
(clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
with clientsocket:
    print('Connected by', address)
    while True:
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        clientsocket.sendall(data)
clientsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
clientsocket.close()
```

and a client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1' #server hostname or IP address
PORT = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(b'Hello world!')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
s.close

print('Received', repr(data))
```

The server listens for a connection, accepts it and echos whatever it receives.

In the python HOWTO it was emphasized to always close a socket.

Now when I run both scripts in seperate terminals the client does as expected:

```
Received b'Hello world!'
```

The terminal with the server gives me the following error:

```
Connected by ('127.0.0.1, 42780')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "echo-server.py", line 19, in <module>
        clientsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

From looking around stackeoverflow I learned that
[it was because of closing the Python file from "the outside", i.e. not from the file object's close()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506392/python-sockets-oserror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor) and I assume this means the socket I am trying to call `socket.shutdown()` on has already been shutdown.

Now when I comment line 19 out in the server script

```
#clientsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RWDR)
```

everything works as expected without any errors.

The terminals show

```
Connected by ('127.0.0.1, 42780')
```

and

```
Received b'Hello world!'
```

From my understanding this behaviour is caused by the with statement.

Now to my actual questions:

1. Does the with statement make calling `socket.shutdown()` unnecessary by completing that task itself?
2. If so, is calling `socket.close()` still necessary or is that done by the with statement aswell? (Commenting that line out didn't give me any different results)

In the end I want to make sure how to close a socket properly from the start since the HOWTO put much emphasis on proper form.

Comment: The `with` statement will call `__enter__` and `__exit__` automatically on the `socket` object. If the `socket` class maps `__exit__` to `close` then it's completely equivalent. See [Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)

Comment: Does that mean calling `socket.close()` is unnecessary but not harmful either? Like calling `fileObject.close()` twice.

Comment: I don't know anything about `socket` objects. I'm just telling you the mechanism.

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects) it says: *Exiting the context manager is equivalent to calling* [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.close).

Comment: Thank you very much. It never ocurred to me to look at the socket.close() call. I only every checked the socket.shutdown() part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`close` is unnecessary in a `with` since it calls close automatically when exiting the `with` block, but `shutdown` can still be called inside the `with` before it exits:

```py
with clientsocket:
    print('Connected by', address)
    while True:
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            clientsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            break
        clientsocket.sendall(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@Peter Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084416/peter-wood) pointed out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) does contain the answer to my question:

> Changed in version 3.2: Support for the context manager protocol was added. Exiting the context manager is equivalent to calling close().

Furthermore:

> Sockets are automatically closed when they are garbage-collected, but it is recommended to close() them explicitly, or to use a with statement around them.

Since calling `fileObject.close()` on a fileObject that [has already been closed does not produce an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954401/python-file-object-allows-you-to-close-a-file-that-is-already-closed) commenting that specific line out did not lead to any different results.

The way I interpret that:

It is not intended to explicitly call `socket.shutdown()` on a socket within a `with` statement.

Calling `socket.close()` on a socket in a `with` statement is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. Just to point out, a socket is not a file object and the same semantics do not automatically apply.