# Is there a defined behaviour for closing a file inside a 'with open' statement in python?

Tags: python, file

If you have a file opened with a `with open` block, then you close the file inside that block, is there a defined behaviour? By my testing, there is no exception raised, but are there any reasons not to?

```
with open('foo', 'w') as f:
    f.write('some data')
    f.close()
    print('file is closed')
with open('foo') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

I ask as in some cases I will need to delete the opened file, so would want to close it first, but code will be cleaner to keep inside the `with` block. Alternatives might be to ditch the `with open` and just use the `open` function, or alternately set a flag to delete the file after the `with` block.

EDIT: example of my use case

```
import os
with open('foo', 'r+') as f:
    d = f.read(n)
    if some_condition():
        f.close()
        os.remove('foo')
    else:
        f.seek(somewhere)
        f.write('something')
```

While I could do it without the context manager, it seems to be best practice to use them. Otherwise I could set a flag to remove the file afterwards, but this seems messier in terms of code, as well as moving the action away from where it gets triggered.

Comment: "cleaner to keep inside the with block"—Doesn't sound that clean: sounds kinda messy.

Comment: It is hard to conceive of a case where 'leave the block' isn't the correct answer, even though `close()` is idempotent. Perhaps you can provide an example of where this is a concern?

Comment: I've added a clearer example of my use case

Answer (score 0):

Closing an already-closed file is an [allowed no-op](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close).

Also see some prior discussion on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954401).

That said, what you're doing sounds odd to me. I would take your
question as a prompt to consider whether you truly want/need
the design you think you need.

Comment: I've added clearer example code of my use case

Comment: @askvictor Your main question has been answered: closing a file within a with block is not a problem. As far as your design choice goes, it's hard to say even with your expanded (but still schematic) example code. I would probably base the decision on how important the program is, how far it has been factored down to single-purpose functions, how finely I wanted to test its functionality, etc. Nothing you've shown us looks entirely unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the `with` statement Python will automatically close the file. You don't need to call `close()` on it. [With statement docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.closed)
print(f.closed)
```

Outputs:

```
False
True
```

Assuming you don't want to delete the opened file inside of your `with` statement there is no reason to call `close()`.

Comment: In fact I do want to delete the opened file inside the with statement, but only in some cases; the other cases the file should close at the end of the `with`.

Comment: @askvictor my thoughts on the matter echo those of FMc's comment on the other answer. I think the answer to this question depends on your code's broader context/purpose.